# Api returning text/html while it should return json

Tags: php, ios, json, api, rest

I am new to web service development. I didn't use any framework. I did it by scratch. I wanted to create an RESTFUL api service which I want to use for my iOS application. But I am getting some error related to content-type

This is my api.php script-

```
<?php

    require_once "scripts/Database.php";
    require_once "scripts/Database_Handler.php";
    require_once "scripts/config.php";

    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); //set the content type

    $db_obj = new Database(); 
    $db = $db_obj->get_database_connection(); //returns the database connection object
    $handler = new Database_Handler($db); //this is the class that does all the queries to database

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; //method is POST here
    $url =  explode("/", $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
    $request = end($url);

    if($request == 'all_products'){
        $result_array = $handler->get_all_products();
    }
    else if ($request == 'customers'){
        $result_array = $handler->get_customers();
    }
    else{
        $result_array = $handler->get_all_products_available_in_stores();
    }

    echo json_encode($result_array);

?>
```

When I try to consume the resource with the help of AFNetworking in iOS, it gives me following error.

```
"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe6b241c0b0> { URL: http://........../....../api.php/customers } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 29 Dec 2015 11:16:01 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.8.0";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://........../....../api.php/customers}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the problem from the api end.

Comment: what is the output of `json_encode()`? Did you try to set the header right before you `echo`? Also, what happens in your script after the `echo`? Does it stop after that?

Comment: What happens if you call the website url in the browser, what is the response?

Comment: yes I tried to set the header right before the encode statement but didn't work. Also when I run through a webpage, it gives me -{"customer_id":"1","customer_first_name":"Mahjabin","customer_last_name":"Alam"},{"customer_id":"2","customer_first_name":"Rafi Al","customer_last_name":"Alam"},{"customer_id":"3","customer_first_name":"Ali","customer_last_name":"Reja"},{"customer_id":"4","customer_first_name":"Maria","customer_last_name":"pierce"},{"customer_id":"5","customer_first_name":"Shipra","customer_last_name":"Sultana"}]

Comment: Please open the URL in Chrome (or Firefox) and add the actual response headers provided in the developer tools.

Comment: I got the issue. I don't know, why it did it but there was an extra line after the closing php tag (?>) in my config.php file. That is why it was not letting me set the header.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: @natasha Some programmers advice skiping the closing php tag. It works fine unless you have some HTML code in the same file.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I did. Can you post your suggestion as an answer, so that I can accept it.